# How to change color AND width of non overlay scrollbars in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, colors, scrollbar

I know many people have complained about the almost invisible and not usable scrollbars in recent versions of Ubuntu, even after removing or disabling the default overlay scrollbars. I wonder how can I easily change their color AND width.

I have a 13.3 inches monitor with a 1600*900 resolution and I can barely see them, as you can see in these images:

[image: http://placerdigital.net/up/Dropbox_003.png]

[image: http://placerdigital.net/up/Nuvola.png]

[image: http://placerdigital.net/up/Ubuntu%20Software%20Center_004.png]

I already changed Firefox, LibreOffice and some other software's scrollbars using GNOME Color Chooser:

[image]

By the way, I'm using Unity. Thanks!

Comment: Screenshot would be nice.

Comment: A screenshot is a must I think in this case. Since the provided answer isn't what you wanted.

Comment: Hi @UriHerrera and Anwar, I already added some images. Thanks!

Comment: Please for the love of god why won't the devs just make this easy to change under system settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note:*

*The formattings in this answer are optimal for precise (Ubuntu 12.04) only, see next answer for improved formattings for trusty (Ubuntu 14.04).*

---

## Make scrollbars visible (change color)

Based on vasa1's informations provided above I changed the color of the classic scrollbars to the default selection color - the same that overlay scrollbars are using as well.

### For GTK 3 applications modify:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css
```

starting from line 1580 so that it looks like:

```
.scrollbar.slider,
.scrollbar.slider:hover,
.scrollbar.button,
.scrollbar.slider.vertical,
.scrollbar.button.vertical {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, right top,
                                     from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.38)),
                                     to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.22)));
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;

    -unico-border-gradient: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, right top,
                                           from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.14)),
                                           to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.14)));
    -unico-centroid-texture:  url("assets/scrollbar_handle_vertical.png");
    -unico-inner-stroke-gradient: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, right top,
                                                 from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.46)),
                                                 to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.3)));
    -unico-inner-stroke-width: 1px;
}

.scrollbar.slider.vertical:hover {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, right top,
                                     from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.28)),
                                     to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.02)));
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;

    -unico-border-gradient: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, right top,
                                           from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 0.94)),
                                           to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 0.94)));
    -unico-centroid-texture:  url("assets/scrollbar_handle_vertical.png");
    -unico-inner-stroke-gradient: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, right top,
                                                 from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.36)),
                                                 to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.1)));
    -unico-inner-stroke-width: 1px;
}

.scrollbar.slider.horizontal,
.scrollbar.button.horizontal {                                   
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.38)),
                                     to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.22)));

    -unico-border-gradient: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                           from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.14)),
                                           to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.14)));
    -unico-centroid-texture:  url("assets/scrollbar_handle.png");
    -unico-inner-stroke-gradient: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                                 from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.46)),
                                                 to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.3)));
}

.scrollbar.slider.horizontal:hover {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.28)),
                                     to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.02)));

    -unico-border-gradient: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                           from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 0.94)),
                                           to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 0.94)));
    -unico-centroid-texture:  url("assets/scrollbar_handle.png");
    -unico-inner-stroke-gradient: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                                 from (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.36)),
                                                 to (shade (@selected_bg_color, 1.1)));
}


.scrollbar.button,
.scrollbar.button:insensitive {
    -unico-outer-stroke-width: 0;
}
```

This should be default.

### For GTK 2 applications modify:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

starting from line 223 so that it looks like:

```
style "scrollbar" = "button" {
    xthickness = 2
    ythickness = 2

    bg[NORMAL] = shade(1.3, @selected_bg_color)
    bg[PRELIGHT] = shade (1.04, @selected_bg_color)

    bg[ACTIVE] = shade (0.96, @selected_bg_color)

    engine "murrine"
    {
        border_shades = {1.15, 1.1}
        roundness = 20
        contrast = 1.0
        trough_shades = {0.92, 0.98}
        lightborder_shade = 1.3
        glowstyle = 5
        glow_shade = 1.02
        gradient_shades = {1.2, 1.0, 1.0, 0.86}
        trough_border_shades = {0.9, 0.98}
    }
}
```

It does not look 100% identical to the GTK 3 formatting, so feel free to improve it.

---

## Make scrollbars clickable (increase width)

To increase the silly **small width** that were never meant for being used in production, I assume, make the following changes to the same files.

### For GTK 3 applications:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css
```

modify line 1550 so that it looks like:

```
.scrollbar {
    -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 0;
    -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 0;
    -GtkRange-slider-width: 16;

    border-radius: 20px;

    -unico-border-gradient: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                           from (shade (@bg_color, 0.74)),
                                           to (shade (@bg_color, 0.74)));
}
```

### For GTK 2 applications modify:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

modify line 34 so that it looks like:

```
GtkScrollbar::slider-width = 16
```

---

For those preferring the complete files already edited, you can download mine from here:

GTK 3: [gtk-widgets.css](http://www.nskcomputing.de/download/files/gtk-widgets.css)

GTK 2: [gtkrc](http://www.nskcomputing.de/download/files/gtkrc)

Be careful. Make backups.

Enjoy! :)

Comment: For those that already read my answer: with last edit I improved the formatting largely. :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you are referring to the overlay scrollbars because you mention Unity.
I don't know how to change the width but you can certainly change the color. If the color is distinct enough, I feel the width isn't that much of a problem because on hover it becomes decently wide.

You need to look in your theme's folder for files called **gtkrc** (in the gtk-2.0 folder) and **gtk-widgets.css** (in the gtk-3.0 folder). Open these files with a text editor. You may need to use `gksudo gedit` instead of just `gedit` if your theme is in /usr/share/themes and not in ~/.themes.
Then, search for **overlay scrollbars** or **overlay-scrollbar** or something similar and play with the colors specified in those sections. You can even specify your own color in hex code.

Obviously, you can set different colors in the two files if you so choose.

To visualize the changes you may need to switch to another theme and back after you've made and saved the changes to these files.

The changes you make in **/usr/share/themes** will be system-wide and changes in **~/.themes** will be user-specific.

This is what my overlay scrollbar looks like in PCManFM.

[image: My overlay scrollbar]

**Edit**: In case, one is using conventional scrollbars, then to increase the contrast between the slider and trough in gtk-3.0 apps such as gedit, one can edit the **gtk-widgets.css** file mentioned above. To do so, search for the section titled **scrollbar** (or something similar) and look for the lines that have something like this:

```
.scrollbar.slider,
.scrollbar.slider:hover,
.scrollbar.button,
.scrollbar.slider.vertical,
.scrollbar.slider.vertical:hover,
.scrollbar.button.vertical {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, right top,
                                 from (shade (@bg_color, 1.08)),
                                 to (shade (@bg_color, 0.92)));
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
```

In here, one can play with the values for the **background-image** by changing the shade. A higher value is brighter, a lower value is darker.

I prefer to do something more simple: I change background-image to background-**color** and just have a color I like. So, for example, background-color: red; would probably give outstanding contrast.

My code looks like this:

```
.scrollbar.slider,
.scrollbar.button,
.scrollbar.slider.vertical,
.scrollbar.button.vertical {
    background-color: #003263; /*@theme_bg_color;*/
    /**/
    /**/
```

Obviously, a backup before editing is advisable and one can comment out stuff in the gtk-widgets.css file instead of deleting things by using `/*` and `*/`.

(I can't get the formatting of block quotes to work while posting answers. If somebody would clean things up, I'd be grateful.)

**One last edit (I hope):**
Users of **Chrome** or **Chromium** may increase contrast by editing their `gtk-2.0/apps/chromium.rc` file if their theme provides it or by editing `gtk-2.0/gtkrc` if what is required is present there.
In both cases one should search for a section headed **style "chrome-gtk-frame"**. In here, again, play with the shade value in this (or similar) line:

```
ChromeGtkFrame::scrollbar-slider-normal-color = shade (1.4, @panel_bg)
```

Or one can simply specific a color like this:

```
ChromeGtkFrame::scrollbar-slider-normal-color = "#003263"
```

or

```
ChromeGtkFrame::scrollbar-slider-normal-color = "blue"
```

(The quotes are required.)

Comment: I'm sorry, @vasa1! I forgot to mention that I removed the overlay scrollbars using "Unsettings" or some commands. Now I have narrow and low-contrast scrollbars. That's what I need to fix. (I already edited the original question).

Comment: @Chuqui, could you please mention a few specific apps which are problematic? And do mention which theme you are using. I know of at least one theme that has very thin scrollbars. In that case, it may just be a matter of trying another theme.

Comment: Hi @vasa1, I want to thank you again for the detailed instructions you gave me. I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question.

Above you can see images of applications where the scrollbars are hard to see: Nautilus, Nuvola Player and Ubuntu Software Center. On the contrary, using Gnome Color Chooser I could change Firefox, Ubuntu One and other software's scrollbars, like LibreOffice.

I'm using the default theme: Ambiance

Comment: The edit I provided should point you to how you could increase contrast even for Nautilus and USC. I don't know about Nuvola. IMO, the default scrollbar width in Ambiance isn't too bad (once you tweak the contrast).

Comment: Very nice answer. How do come to know whether an application uses GTK 2 or GTK 3?Ex nautilus, gedit uses  GTK 3 but firefox/thunderbird uses GTK 2. Is there any way to find it out?

Answer (score 2):

For **Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)** slightly different modifications are needed.

GTK 3: [gtk-widgets.css](http://www.nskcomputing.de/download/ambiance-trusty/gtk-widgets.css) goes to: /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css

GTK 2: [gtkrc](http://www.nskcomputing.de/download/ambiance-trusty/gtkrc) goes to: /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc

Make backups prior:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc.bak
sudo cp gtkrc /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/
sudo cp /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css.bak
sudo cp gtk-widgets.css /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/
```

Those commands expects the downloaded files `gtkrc` and `gtk-widgets.css` in the current directory.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better as an edit to your other answer?

Comment: My intention for a separate answer was to clearly separate 12.04 stuff from 14.04 so that consumers of my prepared layout files are able to find the right ones quickly and without being confused. But ... well ... one can argue about ... ;)